# No DNS after connecting to VPN (with Primo-VPN software)

Tags: network, catalina, vpn, remote-desktop, dns

I use Primo-VPN (bought, but poor support and service, don't buy this) to connect to a PPTP VPN server at my work.

I know PPTP is not the best, but it is what as been setup by the staff there...

I have to connect to the VPN using option : Default route : ON and Use DNS : ON

So when I'm connected to the VPN, it "scrap" my DNS on the Mac.
I'm able to ping IPs like 8.8.8.8, but it is impossible to resolve google.com or any other address.

What is more strange, if *before* opening the VPN connection I had a video-conference open, *after* the connection it still works!
But if I close the app, after this I'm unable to use it (no Internet connection detected).

I use macOs Catalina (10.15.7, latest version for MacIntel)

I can provide some info from command line : `scutil --dns`

DNS configuration * AFTER being connected to the VPN *

```
resolver #1
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
  nameserver[1] : 1.0.0.1
  if_index : 5 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

Comment: Not sure what your are asking for. If a VPN is connected, it must use the remote site's DNS, as otherwise domains in the remote network cannot be resolved. If that DNS does not resolve google.com etc., that may well be intentional.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

With a PC on Windows, connecting to the same VPN, I just need to uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network" and that way I can use Internet without problem on my local computer...

I just want the same behavior on my Mac.

Comment: I don't know Primo-VPN, but not using the default gateway probably means split tunneling. I would assume that _Default route : ON_ send all traffic through the VPN, and setting it to _OFF_ would consequently split traffic. However, I'm not sure if that also means that different DNS servers are used. Did you try this?

Comment: Since your nameservers are set to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, these are Cloudflare DNS servers which should work perfectly. What does `nslookup google.com` and `dig google.com` give you? It could be that you _can_ resolve google.com, but the VPN won't let you got out to the internet from the remote network for security reasons which is not uncommon, if it is a company VPN you are connecting to.

Comment: I did try to put Default route to OFF, but I can't connect with Remote Desktop on my work PC when I do this.

With nslookup and dig, I get connection timed out; no servers could be reached.

However, if I ping the Google DNS, it works :
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=118 time=46.419 ms
...
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=118 time=50.144 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 40.047...

Comment: Why do you ping Google DNS when your DNS is set to Cloudflare? Did you try ‘nslookup’ with both of them? Please add your commands and results to your question.